# R data frame table set the values into columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns

There is a table:

```
class<-c("A","B", "B","C","D","D","D")
value<-c(1,3,2,5,6,2,5)
df<-cbind(class,value)
```

[image]

For example, the classes "B" and "C" have more than one value. I want to set every value of the class into a separate column. I would like to get the following output:

[image]

Could You please help me?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
Inna

Comment: See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

First of all, make it a dataframe using `data.frame()`

```
class <- c("A","B", "B","C","D","D","D")
value <- c(1,3,2,5,6,2,5)
df <- data.frame(class,value)

# A bunch of packages that might help you.
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(new_names = paste0("value", 1:n())) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = new_names)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   class [4]
  class value1 value2 value3
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A          1     NA     NA
2 B          3      2     NA
3 C          5     NA     NA
4 D          6      2      5
```

(I would not put `0` - `NA` is the specific solution if a value is missing)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. NA can be always replaced. It's not a problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` and `rbind` and fill the missing with `lapply` and `[`:

```
x <- split(df[,2], df[,1])
do.call("rbind", lapply(x, "[", 1:max(lengths(x))))
#  [,1] [,2] [,3]
#A "1"  NA   NA  
#B "3"  "2"  NA  
#C "5"  NA   NA  
#D "6"  "2"  "5"
```